# How do I get the Last column of the array to add up at the end?

Tags: java

The part of the code that is getting me stuck is the end print out and getting it to add the BILL parts of the array for the final system.out message and display it correctly.  The array and the rest of the program work fine it is just that last part that I am having trouble with.

```
private static void printBilling() { 

        int numberOfCustomers = Accounts.length;
        int sum=0;

        System.out.println("\n\nTable showing charges for cell phones");
        for (int customer=0; customer<numberOfCustomers; customer++){           
            System.out.printf ("%s %s %s:\n GB used = %s Please Pay %s \n\n", 
                    Accounts[customer][NAME], 
                    Accounts[customer][ACCT], 
                    Accounts[customer][SELECTION],
                    Accounts[customer][USED],
                    Accounts[customer][BILL]); 
         }

            sum+= Accounts.length[customer][BILL];
        {
        System.out.printf ("The total owed is %s", +sum);   
        }
```

Comment: That shouldn't compile -- `Accounts.length` is an int, not an array. Why not just get rid of the `.length` part?

Comment: When i drop the length it wont compile either.  That was just what i ended up with after messing around with a few different things.

Comment: That's because you need to put that *into* the loop as well, and format your curly braces to that they make your code easier to read and debug. You're asking some basic questions, questions that likely are best answered by studying your notes and introductory tutorials.

Comment: Think what you're trying to do -- add array items inside of a loop -- that means that the addition must be done inside of the loop -- makes common sense when you think about it, no?

Comment: I've moved the for loops end brace to proper position so you can now **see** that your summation statement is **outside** of the loop. Code formatting isn't done to make the code look pretty, it's to make it easier to understand and debug, and your improper indention is interfering with your ability to see that the summation is not being done in the loop.

Comment: I know that.  Ive tidied the code up and put it in the loop, but it it still will not compile even with sum+= Accounts[customer][BILL].  I'm trying to figure out what part of the equation I am messing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your bill probably is a String then change like below.

if it contains integer, use this

```
 sum+= Integer.parseInt(Accounts[customer][BILL]);
```

if it contains doubles, need (double sum variable) then use

```
sum+= Double.parseDouble(Accounts[customer][BILL]);
```

Comment: Ya it was a string with doubles so it was the second one.  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: nice to hear it. cheers